# Blender - Quick Liquid - Domain is a glass cube

Tags: fluid-simulation, mantaflow

In Blender 3.3.0, "*Quick liquid*" creates a domain which is rendered as a glass cube.

I tried in several ways but please check the most straightforward one:

1. Brand-new Blender session
   [image: startup setup]
2. Change the engine to Cycles, render the default cube without problem
   [image: default render output]
3. Apply *Quick liquid*
   [image: quick liquid setup]
4. Without any further modification, it renders the following:
   [image: quick liquid render]

Thank you very much for your help in advance!

Comment: Welcome to BSE. Would you mind editing your question and clarifying exactly what you expect to happen when you hit render? As per the steps you outlined, Blender is attempting to create liquid from the default cube. The simulation is pretty ugly with the default settings, but it is behaving as it should. What you are seeing in the render is the default cube, plus the simulated liquid.

Comment: Please watch tutorials on fluid simulation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Quick Liquid does 2 things.

**1.**

It sets up a *domain* object (some cube-like shape) around the currently selected object. It gives this object a default glass material and sets it to be displayed as a wireframe in the viewport.

**2.**

It turns on fluid *domain* physics for the domain object. For the selected object (your default cube) it sets up fluid *emitter* physics.

So the behavior you're seeing is perfectly normal.

You might want to learn more about fluid simulation in Blender.

Here's a CGCookie tutorial that might have some good info for you: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6B0QM4Cft5c

Comment: Dear Samuel - my bad, the advices and the link helped a lot! Really perfect tutorial, now everything looks perfect! 
Thank you very much!

Comment: Happy to help, István!

Answer (score 2):

The quick effect operators only set up an object for a given type of simulation, you have yet to actually do the simulation, aka "bake" it.
For a liquid, specifically, baking will deform the domain mesh into the simulated liquid shape. If nothing is baked, then the domain just keeps its normal form: a cuboid.

By default, the baking occurs when you start a playback from the start frame.
So you can hit <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>← Left arrow</kbd> to jump to the start frame, and then hit <kbd>space</kbd> to playback. You should see the domain mesh deform frame after frame. It might take a while depending on your machine, so be patient.

You will also need to enable the mesh option on your domain settings:

[image: mesh option]

Comment: Keep in mind that to see the mesh deform/simulate(instead of just particles), you have to enable the Mesh option in the domain settings before you bake.

Comment: Dear L0Lock, thank you very much - patience and enabling Mesh option helped a lot, it took some time to see the results - but definitely worth it. :) Thank you!